# Wix doesn't include any of the files in the .MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

i am trying to add files in my WIX installer, however it doesn't do that at the moment. i am staring at it for hours now and i just can't see what might be the problem. the referencing seems to work alright as well as the target location. the installer runs fine up to the point when it needs to install files of course.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Wix_setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Frank Jansen" UpgradeCode="37a42e55-dea8-47da-8f4f-fb065dd38a9e">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Wix_setup" Level="1">
      <!--create a seperate ComponentGroupRef and Fragment for each extra added program-->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="InstallationFiles" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="DLLs" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="IniFiles" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Scripts" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="TeamViewer" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Wix_setup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" ></Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
  </Fragment>
```

here is also a part of the references that i made using heat:

```
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Directory Id="dirE31AF1F0EC087256AE3A304B079577CE" Name="Program Files">
    <Directory Id="dir686DC70E77279FD983277BA8C61F0AF5" Name="ActiveX Control Pad">
      <Component Id="cmp50E37DF3A2B94BC9155ED7F4A264B47B" Guid="{F3CE58FB-5E41-4CD9-B761-C1B14A4F6C5F}">
        <File Id="fil0D955E35C33B26A36350F0C4D02733AF" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\MMI installatie bestanden\MMI install files\Program Files\ActiveX Control Pad\license.txt" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp367C764B6CFEC27E7632FB3F5B37A3F9" Guid="{FBEC3C91-3DCD-4CF3-B58D-B7C97AEB8ACF}">
        <File Id="fil084E5B485699543BB060A10BAEEC4519" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\MMI installatie bestanden\MMI install files\Program Files\ActiveX Control Pad\ped.cnt" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp5EF25EC501B2689546C69D7C8B18B79F" Guid="{182C17ED-01E1-4529-A733-D3FBA7FF61EE}">
        <File Id="filF5043624868A85726914B5A383640B6F" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\MMI installatie bestanden\MMI install files\Program Files\ActiveX Control Pad\PEd.exe" />
      </Component>

<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="Wix_database" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp50E37DF3A2B94BC9155ED7F4A264B47B" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp367C764B6CFEC27E7632FB3F5B37A3F9" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp5EF25EC501B2689546C69D7C8B18B79F" />
```

the ComponentGroupRef's and the Fragments they are connected to are currently not yet in use and dont have an impact on the program (the Fragments are left out of this example)

can anybody see what i might have done wrong or what is missing?
thanks in advance,

Comment: Where are you referencing the ComponentGroup `Wix_database`?   If its not ever referenced by a feature, it won't be included in your final MSI.

Comment: Wix_database is a system variable i used with heat in order to create a pathreference.wxs file. Wix_database has a value that points towards the location of the files that need to be added.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, I'm talking about the `Id="Wix_database"` you're showing near the bottom of your second code snippet (this is just a component group Id, not a variable).  That component group needs to be referenced by a feature or else it won't get installed.

Comment: ahh ok, bud to be honest i have no idea with what i need to reference it to, i am using WIX for the first time and to be honest, easy is different and my programming skills are truly basic. i used a video to help me set this up bud i couldn't fint anything he referenced it with. here is a link to the video if you are interested [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTctUffErjs) the part that is applicable to my problem start at around 13 minutes into the video.

Comment: Try adding `<ComponentGroupRef Id="Wix_database" />` inside your `<Feature ...>` tag.

Comment: thanks, however it now throws 2 errors that are related. it has to do with the fact they have the same symbol  bud need to be unique

Comment: If you need help with those errors, please either post a new question, or update your current one with exact error messages and any other relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the errors. it had a conflict with my reference file i still had in the project, because of that it did see it as two references to the same symbol that i declared the way ***heavyd*** suggested.

thanks for the support Heavyd.